# How do I read .pem file in a lambda layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a .pem file in a lambda layer I'm trying to get my code to grab. I thought it was as simple as calling /opt/file.pem however I get a invalid path error. It is located in root directory

Comment: Layers are extracted to the /opt directory in the function execution environment. Did you list the contents of /opt to verify?

Comment: I attempted that however it shows it as empty. I have the layer in place in the lambda with the zip file. Using  `import os
 arr = os.listdir('/opt')
 print(arr)` @jarmod

Comment: I'm not aware that you can deploy a layer with a Lambda function in a single package. Are you sure it's deployed a layer? And you say you found your PEM file in the root of the file system. Really? Seems unlikely.

Comment: The .pem file is in the root dir of the zip I uploaded. I assumed I could just call it from the layer in my lambda. with /opt/file.pem @jarmod

Comment: The root of a regular Lambda function is /var/task/. Make sure that you actually deployed a Lambda layer.

Comment: You are correct that layers [are extracted to the /opt directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). If you're not seeing anything in that directory, you should (1) verify that your Lambda is actually configured to use the layer, and (2) download the layer and verify that it contains the file you expect.

Comment: You should also [verify that you have permission to use the layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-permissions). You should get the correct permissions automatically if you create your function via the Console, but might not with a tool (I'm 99% certain that you won't if using Terraform).